# Haskell: Filter a list of tuples with condition

Tags: haskell, filter

I have a list of tuples on which I want to apply certain condition. Il looks simple but I'm stuck with this. **The list of tuples is all ready generated**

eg : `[(10,11),(11,10),(11,12),(12,11),(13,15),(13,14)]`

I want to return a list of the same tuples but when a tuple (x1,y1) and (x2,y2) where x1 == y2  and y1 = x2  and  belongs to the list only the (x1,y1) one is returned

**My function header**

```
myFun :: Ord a => [(a,a)] -> [(a,a)]
    myFun = ....
```

And the expected result should be like this(from the same list)

```
[(10,11),(11,12),(13,15),(13,14)]
```

Any indications, ideas or hints are welcomed.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: `myFun = nubBy $ \(x1, y1) (x2, y2) -> x1 == y2 && y1 == x2`

Comment: Great, I wish I can understand more  lambda expression

Comment: Also possible: `map head $ groupBy (\(x1, y1) (x2, y2) -> x1 == y2 && x2 == y1) xs`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some trying I came up with this:

```
myFun::Ord a => [(a,a)] -> [(a,a)]
myFun ls = auxfun [] ls

auxfun:: Eq a => [(a,a)] -> [(a,a)] -> [(a,a)]
auxfun [] [] = []
auxfun [] (l:ls) = auxfun [l] ls
auxfun ls [] = ls
auxfun ls1 ((x,y):ls2)
    |(y,x) `elem` ls1 = auxfun ls1 ls2
    |otherwise = auxfun ((x,y):ls1) ls2
```

This will return you [(13,14),(13,15),(11,12),(10,11)] in your test case, in case the order matters you can just reverse it.

This solution is without using any libraries, else you can use a nubBy like another person said.

Comment: @Alexis King answer in the comment section do the job, but thanks for your effort, I'll try this one too

Answer (score 3):

I see it has been answered already, but since haskell is so much fun and there are always more possible solutions I'll add one that I found:

```
foldr (\x y -> if x == rev (head) y then (x:tail y) else x:y) [rev $ last xs] xs where
  rev (a,b) = (b,a)
```